# Increase the width of TabContainer header

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

I have a vertical TabContainer, but I can't fix the width of the TabPanel (it will increase a little, but not to the full width of the text).  Text is hidden behind the ContentTemplate.  For example:

[image: Screenshot of hidden Tab Header text.]

Here's the markup:

```
  <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" Visible="false"  UseVerticalStripPlacement="true">
       <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" >
             <HeaderTemplate>
                   <div style="width: 200px">General Examination </div>
             </HeaderTemplate>
             <ContentTemplate>  </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:TabPanel>
```

How can I fix the width of the tabs to that they are all same?  The second tab, "General Examination", is not fully visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some CSS for the tab headers.  The style that applies to that element of the AJAX Control Toolkit TabContainer is named `.ajax__tab_header_verticalleft`.  Something like this should work:

```
.ajax__tab_header_verticalleft 
{
    width: 200px;
}
```

You might be able to dial back a bit from 200px, but that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help anyone else facing the same problem.

provide VerticalStripWidth="150px" in asp:TabContainer